# how to update nested object in array using nodejs with mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, postman

In MongoDB My Database structure is like this below,

```
[{
    "_id": "",
    "courseTitle": "",
    "courseImage": "",
    "group": [
        {
            "_id": "",
            "title": "",
            "overView": "",
            "duration": "",
            "syllabus": []
        }
    ],
 }]
```

In my node js server I'm trying to update my record using put method, here is my route

```
router.put("/:id/:gid", (req, res) => {
let updateRecord = {
title: req.body.title,
duration: req.body.duration,
overView: req.body.overView,
syllabus: req.body.syllabus,
};
```

I'm using findOne to update my record,

```
GroupCourse.findOne({ "group._id": req.params.gid }, function (error, data) {
if (error) {
  console.log(error);
  res.status(500).send();
} else {
  if (!data) {
    console.log("404");
    res.status(404).send();
  } else {
    if (data) {
      data = updateRecord;
  console.log("This is updated data", data)
    }
```

If I console.log(data), The data shows updated values.
When i tried to save the data with the below code, It throws the error..

```
 data.save(function (error, updatedData) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log("This is Updated", updatedData);
         res.send(updatedData);
      }
      else {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send();
      }
    });
    }
   }
 });
});
```

I'm using NodeJs and MongoDB and Postman to send send data

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
GroupCourse.update({'_id': req.params.id,'group._id': req.params.gid}, 
{'$set': {
    'group.$.title': updateRecord.title,
    'group.$.duration': updateRecord.duration
}}, function(err,response) {
  // check error and response
}
```

option 2

```
GroupCourse.findOne({'_id': req.params.id}).then(doc => {
  // can update parent
  // item.courseTitle= 'javascript'
  item = doc.group.id(req.params.gid );
  item["title"] = updateRecord.title;
  item["duration"] = updateRecord.duration;
  doc.save();

  //sent response to client
}).catch(err => {
  // error
});
```